# Вывести с помощью указателей из строки символ с наименьшим кодом

Tags: c, массивы, алгоритм, строки, память

В задании нужно вывести символ из строки с наименьшим кодом. Выдает ошибку: "Segmentation fault. Core dumped" Подозреваю, что проблема в цикле while. Прошу не обращать внимание на "минимальность" кода и его "кошмарность", так как в задании указано не использовать обычные переменные вообще и выделять память динамически. Спасибо.

Вот пример кода:

```
/*нужные хедеры*/  

int main(void){

    char * inputStr = NULL;
    int * minASCIIcode = NULL;
    char * minCodeChar = NULL; /* needs no memory */
    char * Charptr = NULL; /*needs no memory; links to the memory of       each element of inputStr */
    int * count = NULL;

      /* memory allocation */
     inputStr = (char *) malloc(50 * sizeof(char));
     minASCIIcode = (int *) malloc(1 * sizeof(int));
     count = (int *) malloc (1 * sizeof(int));

     if (NULL == inputStr || NULL == minASCIIcode){
            printf("Ошибка");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

    /* algorithm */

    scanf("%s", inputStr);

    *count = 0;
    *minASCIIcode = (int)(*(inputStr + *count));
    Charptr = inputStr;

    while(NULL != Charptr){

          if( (int)(*Charptr) < *minASCIIcode){
          (*minASCIIcode) = (int)(*Charptr);
          minCodeChar = Charptr;
        }
        (*count)++;
        Charptr = (inputStr + (*count)); 
    }


    printf("символ: ");
    putchar(*minCodeChar);


      /* memory deallocation */
    free(inputStr);
    free(minASCIIcode);
    free(count);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```

Comment: Под отладчиком программу прошагайте и всё увидите своими глазами.

Answer (score 1):

Не буду комментировать сам алгоритм (он кошмарен, скорее всего "с помощью указателей" не означает именно такой подход). Но обратите внимание:

```
minASCIIcode = (int *) malloc(1 * sizeof(int));
inputStr = (char *) malloc(50 * sizeof(char));
```

Здесь мы сохранили адреса выделенной памяти в указателях `minASCIIcode` и `inputStr`.

```
while(inputStr != NULL){
```

Странное условие, возможно, имелось в виду `while( *inputStr != 0 )`. Но и от этого толку мало, так как...

```
  }
  inputStr++;
```

...в этой строке мы теряем адрес выделенной памяти. К тому же `inputStr` может увеличиваться до тех пор, пока его значение не станет равным 0. Теоретически. На практике уйдём далеко-далеко за конец строки, и будем перебирать всю имеющуюся в компьютере память. До тех пор, пока не наткнёмся на область, которую читать запрещено, и вылетим с `Segmentation fault` или чем-то вроде.

А если не тут вылетим, то тут:

```
free(inputStr);
free(minASCIIcode);
```

Потому что во `free()` передаётся непонятно что (правильные значения мы потеряли выше).

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static int minCharCode( const char *str )
{
    const char *ptr = str;
    const char *minCharPtr = str;

    while( *ptr ) {
        /* не забываем про signed/unsigned char */
        if( *ptr < *minCharPtr ) {
            minCharPtr = ptr;
        }
        ptr++;
    }
    return *minCharPtr;
}

int main( void )
{
    int c;
    char *string = malloc( 50 );

    fgets( string, 50, stdin );
    string[strlen( string ) - 1] = 0;

    c = minCharCode( string );
    printf( "%d ('%c')\n",  c, c );

    free( string );
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, не понятно, почему вы динамически выделяете память под переменные, ведь задание состоит всего лишь в том, чтобы найти символ с наименьшим кодом с помощью указателя.

Во-вторых, если речь идет о кодах то вам следует рассматривать их как неотрицательные числа.

В-третьих, функция `fgets` может добавить символ новой строки в символьный массив, и тогда этот символ всегда будет иметь наименьший код. Вы должны исключить его из рассмотрения.

Что касается ошибки выполнения, то данное условие цикла

```
while(inputStr != NULL){
```

будет всегда истинным,так как вы уже проверили выше, что указатель не равен `NULL`.

```
 if (NULL == inputStr || NULL == minASCIIcode){
        printf("Ошибка");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
```

Кроме того, так как указатель inputStr инкрементируется в цикле, то вызов функции

```
free(inputStr);
```

приведет к неопределенному поведению программы.

Программа может выглядеть следующим образом.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N   50

int main(void) 
{
    char s[N];

    printf( "Enter a string (no more than %d symbols): ", N );

    if ( fgets( s, sizeof( s ), stdin ) && *s != '\n' && *s != '\0' )
    {
        char *min = s;

        for ( char *p = s; *p != '\n' && *p != '\0'; ++p )
        {
            if ( ( unsigned char )*p < ( unsigned char )*min )
            {
                min = p;
            }
        }

        printf( "the minimum char %c with code %d at position %d\n", 
                *min, ( unsigned char )*min, ( int )( min - s ) );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Диалог с программой может выглядеть следующим образом:

```
Enter a string (no more than 50 symbols): Sergei
the minimum char S with code 83 at position 0
```

Если вам все же надо исходный массив выделять динамически, то, надеюсь, вы самостоятельно можете изменить эту программу, включив в нее динамическое выделение памяти для массива.